# Rails 4 Nested Forms Simple_form_for & simple_field_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm just trying to generate a simple nested form, like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for @profile do |f| %>
<%= f.input :first_name %>
<%= f.input :last_name %>
<%= f.input :phone_number %>
<%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |p| %>
  <%= p.input :street %>
  <%= p.input :city %>
  <%= p.input :state, collection: us_states %>
  <%= p.input :zip_code %>
<% end %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
```

My models:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

My controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_customer!

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end
end
```

Unfortunately that nested attribute `addresses` doesn't populate anything on the page, I would expect to see fields like `street` or `city` but I get nothing.

However, if I change `<%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |p| %>` to `<%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |p| %>` the fields display correctly.

Unfortunately doing this causes issues because I can't use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` helper as outlined in the docs (as far as I can tell).  Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: are you using .build in your profile controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to build the profile and the addresses in the `#new` action for it to work.  Revised working code:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_customer!

  def new
    @profile = current_customer.build_profile
    @profile.addresses.build
  end
end
```

You'll need to look at how your params come through, but since I have a `has_many`, they came through hashed with a key of a record id.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because nested forms require created objects to work. It looks like Profile gets instantiated but Address does not.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_customer!

  def new
   @profile = Profile.new
   @profile.addresses.create   # this will create the address object that the nested form will use
  end
end
```

I think you will need to create Profile as well rather than create an instance of it.

```
@profile = Profile.create
```

I've just been working with nested forms myself and this is how it worked for me.

Comment: thanks doz, I got it working and I'll share my answer.